# How to link a ClassLibrary with .NET Web api in AWS Elastic Bean Stack?

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed the .NET Web api which references a .NET Class Library(Class Library has DBContext and ado.net Entity framework filess) in Elastic bean stack. While the .NET Web api has an option to deploy into EBS, class library does not have any option. My project in EBS references the class library in my desktop. Which is why I am not able to access the api. How can I reference the Class library, do I have to add the class library to S3?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which method you are using to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, you should be able to package all your assemblies in a zip file and upload that.

The documentation provided by AWS makes it sound like dependencies should be deployed automatically if you use their toolkit, as well:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.quickstart.html

It's worth checking what happens in the output folder when you publish your project. Does your dependency get copied in?